# FInd largest files and directories for a specific user

Tags: linux, file

I am new to linux and I would like to find the 10 largest files and directories belonging to a specific user, how should I go about doing this?

Thank you
Crouz

Answer (score 2):

directories:

```
du $usershome | sort -nr | head -n10
```

files:

```
find $usershome -exec stat --format '%s %n' \{\} \; | sort -nr | head -n10
```

edit:
by owner

directories:

```
find / -user $username -type d -exec du --max-depth=1 \{\} \; | sort -nr | head -n10
```

files:

```
find / -user $username -type f -exec stat --format '%s %n' \{\} \; | sort -nr | head -n10
```

Comment: Thank you, but I meant files belonging or created by a specific username, not necesseraly in the user's home directory